# Java multithreading : Execute 2 threads one after other to print from 1 to 10 in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Two threads needs to print in this order-

Thread1:0

Thread2:::0

Thread1:1

Thread2:::1

Thread1:2

Thread2:::2

Thread1:3

Thread2:::3

.

.

.

Thread1:10

Thread2:::10

My current is as below:

```
package sample;
public class ThreadExecutionOrder {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
ThreadExecutionOrder th=new ThreadExecutionOrder();
Thread1 t1= new Thread1(th);
Thread t2 = new Thread2(th);
t1.start();
t2.start();
}
}
class Thread1 extends Thread{
ThreadExecutionOrder th;
Thread1(ThreadExecutionOrder th){
    this.th=th;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Thread1:"+i);   
        synchronized(th){
            try {
                th.wait();
                th.notify();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
}
class Thread2 extends Thread{
ThreadExecutionOrder th;
Thread2(ThreadExecutionOrder th){
    this.th=th;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Thread2:::"+i); 

        synchronized(th){
            th.notify();
            try {
                th.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }   
    }
}
}
```

This questions was asked in an interview. Please let me know how to solve this with example code. Thanks.

Comment: Threads are scheduled by the OS. Serialize them makes no sense.

Comment: So, that current code. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: @efekctive, I would disagree. Thread synchronization via different kinds of barriers is very useful when pack of executors should wait for everyone to finish current step before starting on next step.

Comment: You are confusing serialization with synchronization. To print in order a loop is enough

Comment: The above code is not printing in the required fashion. I am also aware that threads execution order is dependent on thread schedular but this is the question asked in an interview so asking in here.

Comment: We can’t look into the interviewer’s head. Perhaps, explaining, how nonsensical this task is, would be the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for each thread, granting it permission to print the next line of output, like this:

```
public class CounterThread extends Thread {
    private final Semaphore mySemaphore;
    private final Semaphore nextSemaphore;
    public CounterThread(String name, Semaphore mySemaphore, Semaphore nextSemaphore) {
        super(name);
        this.mySemaphore = mySemaphore;
        this.nextSemaphore = nextSemaphore;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                this.mySemaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println(getName() + ":" + i);
                this.nextSemaphore.release();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

With object monitors, the `notify()` call only signals threads that are already waiting. If no thread is currently waiting, the signal is "lost".

With semaphores, the `release()` call adds a permit to the semaphore, which can immediate cause an already waiting thread to begin executing, or it is remembered so some future thread can continue executing when it calls `acquire()`, without ever entering a wait state.

*Test (2 threads)*

```
Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore(0);
new CounterThread("Thread1", s1, s2).start();
new CounterThread("Thread2", s2, s1).start();
s1.release(); // Start the counting
```

*Output*

```
Thread1:0
Thread2:0
Thread1:1
Thread2:1
Thread1:2
Thread2:2
Thread1:3
Thread2:3
Thread1:4
Thread2:4
Thread1:5
Thread2:5
Thread1:6
Thread2:6
Thread1:7
Thread2:7
Thread1:8
Thread2:8
Thread1:9
Thread2:9
Thread1:10
Thread2:10
```

*Test (4 threads)*

Can be used with more than 2 threads:

```
Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore s3 = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore s4 = new Semaphore(0);
new CounterThread("Thread1", s1, s2).start();
new CounterThread("Thread2", s2, s3).start();
new CounterThread("Thread3", s3, s4).start();
new CounterThread("Thread4", s4, s1).start();
s1.release(); // Start the counting
```

*Output*

```
Thread1:0
Thread2:0
Thread3:0
Thread4:0
Thread1:1
Thread2:1
Thread3:1
Thread4:1
Thread1:2
Thread2:2
Thread3:2
Thread4:2
Thread1:3
Thread2:3
Thread3:3
Thread4:3
Thread1:4
Thread2:4
Thread3:4
Thread4:4
Thread1:5
Thread2:5
Thread3:5
Thread4:5
Thread1:6
Thread2:6
Thread3:6
Thread4:6
Thread1:7
Thread2:7
Thread3:7
Thread4:7
Thread1:8
Thread2:8
Thread3:8
Thread4:8
Thread1:9
Thread2:9
Thread3:9
Thread4:9
Thread1:10
Thread2:10
Thread3:10
Thread4:10
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that this is a useful task, but it can be implemented like

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(2);
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    int thread = i;
    es.execute(() -> {
        String name = "Thread "+(thread+1)+": ";
        for(int turn=0; turn<22; turn++) {
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            if((turn&1)==thread)
                System.out.println(name+turn/2);
        }
    });
}
es.shutdown();
```

The lambda expression is only a syntactical thing, not required for the program logic. It would be easy to convert it to Java versions before Java 8. Also, letting the second thread print three colons instead of one (if that really is a requirement), wouldn’t be so hard…